# Unable to run a simple es6 Nodejs application

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6

I've created a simple nodejs express application:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
app.listen(3000, => (req, res) {
  res.sendFile("index.html") 
})
```

It throws an exception:

```
app.listen(3000, => (req, res) {
                 ^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token =>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be the other way round? I mean `(req, res) => { ... }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `arrow` function should be like this

```
app.listen(3000,(req, res) =>
```

or without `arrow`, it would be like this

```
app.listen(3000, function (req,res) {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
})
```

Comment: @Dorion That's because you never defined `path`.

Comment: @Dorion: That means there is another issue in your code that you have to fix. Is something unclear about the error message?

Comment: @Dorion you need to require `path` like this `const path = require('path');`

Comment: @Dorion try to resolve such kind of simple errors yourself!

Comment: now "TypeError: Cannot read property 'sendFile' of undefined"

Comment: @Dorion the function is `sendfile` and not `sendFile`.

Comment: @Dorion and `res` is undefined as it should be written in `app.get` and not `app.listen`